# Are there any studies detailing the overall "-omics" effects of using bleach to synchronise a C. elegans population?

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology, development, embryology

I wasn’t able to find papers detailing the changes in the transcriptome/proteome of *C. elegans* when synchronised by bleaching vs not-bleaching. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction!